# AdminLte2 - strange behavior in control sidebar

Tags: adminlte

I'have implemented AdminLTE2 and I'm having some problem with the control sidebar.

The behavior is really strange:

If I click on the link:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
```

The content is not appearing but if I try to: load the page, change the browser tab while is loading and to come back to the page... If I click on the href the control sidebar appears properly...

I don't know whats is happening.
How can I fix it ?

Thanks to support

Answer (score 0):

Which AdminLTE Version you use?

Can you provide your code or a link?

Did you checked your browser console for JavaScript errors?